# React Native : Displaying specific content from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, parsing

I have `Sampling_Instructions` that contains an array of objects according to the example I listed below and my goal is to display only the **Body** information.
**Pay attention,
green apple**
What is the right way to do this?

```
"Sampling_Instructions":"[{\"Timestamp\":\"2022-09-18T11:50:00\",\"From_User_ID\":20,\"Type\":\"Sampling_Instructions\",\"Body\":\"Pay attention\"},
{\"Timestamp\":\"2022-09-10T11:20:00\",\"From_User_ID\":20,\"Type\":\"Sampling_Instructions\",\"Body\":\"green apple\"}]",
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do it because the information looks strange as you can see.

Comment: “Strange” how?  At a glance this looks like *part* of a JavaScript object, a single property which is a string.  That string looks like a JSON-encoded array of objects.  If there’s a problem, it’s not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON parse like this

```
let samplingInstructions = JSON.parse(JSON.parse( sampling instruction ))
console.log(samplingInstructions[0].Body)
```